# Apache .htaccess rewrite parameter to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got an application that has been migrated to a newer platform. The tasks are similar and I'd like to redirect a GET parameter to a directory. For example

```
http://gallery/index.php?gal=ABC  =>  http://photos/gal/ABC
  and
http://gallery/?gal=DEF           =>  http://photos/gal/DEF
```

and the anything that doesn't get caught redirect it to `http://photos`

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^(/index.php)$ /%1/%2?
```

However all I get is a 404 and no redirection. Similarly, I've tried

```
RedirectMatch ^/index\.php\?=gal(.*) http://photos/gal/$1
```

but I'm having trouble escaping the `?` in the original URL.

What would be the proper way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file and insert the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://photos %1/%2? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Had to fix the extra space between `photos %1` but other than that all is good! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your order is reversed. Rewrite it in front of you

`RewriteRule /(.+)\/(.+) index.php?$1=$2`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Nothing happens. I can confirm the .htaccess file is working because entering `RedirectMatch /(.+) http://photos/$1` works just fine routing `http://gallery/index.php?gal=ABC` `=>` `http://photos/?gal=ABC`

Comment: You visit `http://photos/gal/ABC` to see if it will jump to `http://gallery/index.php?gal=ABC`

Comment: I'd like to go the other way around. `http://gallery/index.php?gal=ABC  =>  http://photos/gal/ABC`

Comment: Try this, start to misunderstand what you mean

Comment: That's okay. It's still not working however. I'm using [this checker tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) also to make sure it's not anything wrong with my apache config and even so it's telling me `This rule was not met` when I feed it `http://gallery/index.php?gal=ABC`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$  http://photos %1/%2? [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: this is ok,try it

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but might be still relevant for others, so I suggest a slightly different general approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} key=([0-9a-zA-Z]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1? [R=302,L]
```

Notes:

- QUERY_STRING in the condition checks for a param name "key" and catches it's value
- The rewrite rule adds the param value as directory using %1. Note the ? removes the original query part from end result

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the different approach! I didn't know you could take a parameter like that in the condition. However just to make it work with the question, does this solution a) redirect from `http://gallery/...` to `http://photos/...` and b) if no key is provided, will it catch and redirect to just `http://photos/`?

Comment: As of the redirection - you would edit the rewrite rule, instead of having /%1 set here a different path. And about (b) correct - no param - no added dir.